# strncpy_s does not work if the second parameter set to be 1

Tags: strncpy

I am so curious why for `strncpy_s`, when I set the second parameter `numberOfElements` to 1, it does not copy the first character to the destination. And when I set it to 2, it copy the first one to destination.
For example:

```
int main()
{
    char a[16];
    strncpy_s(a, 1, "1+1=2", _TRUNCATE);
    return 0;
}
```

Then in debugger, I found `a[0] = 0'\0'`. Why it is not `a[0] = '1'`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the string "1" takes up two bytes and there's only room for one.

A C-style string has to have a terminating zero byte, otherwise there is no way to know its length. With just space for one character, the only possible legal string is just a terminator.